# TFS Merge Discard Command

Tags: tfs

I'd like to discard a large number of **non-continuous** changesets that are currently eligible for merging between two branches.

Assuming that C100,C103 and C105 are the three changesets pending a merge, can I use the following command to discard them all, without any unpleasant side effects? i.e. affecting / including changesets C102, C104 on other branches?

`tf merge $/sourceBranch $/targetBranch /discard /recursive /version:C100~C105`

It seems highly unlikely that they would be affected, but I'd appreciate any confirmation possible, as I'm quite keen not to trash my new company's source control!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally plucked up the courage to run the `tf merge` command using a non-continuous range of changesets via `/version:Cx~Cz` (rather than discard 100+ changesets individually), and as expected it worked perfectly, so my paranoia about breaking the company's source control was unfounded (And of course I could have un-done the pending merge discards anyway).

Hopefully this may reassure someone doing some scary merging in the future!